# how to import public certificate for tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, pkix

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: basic constraints check failed: this is not a CA certificate

Comment: Actually I am running my webservice client from my local m/c and the webservice itself is running on production server.But this is giving the above error.The end point reference I am using is correct because the wsdl file is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use your webapp as a client to a service based on https? If so you´re webapp should be able to trust that service. If the service is created with a self-signed certificate you need to add that cert´s CA root certificate to your cacerts as trusted. That can be done with a keytool which comes with the jre/jdk.

```
keytool.exe -import -alias AliasForYourTrustedCert -file File.cer -trustcacerts -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
```